# Full dataset columns value_counts().to_frame() using for to append to a file in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

I'm struggling with pandas using Google Colab. Let me explain my situation:

I'm trying to generate data['column'].value_counts() for each column in my dataset (This data set contains around 1530 columns with data (some of them are just empty because format to recolect data), so when I used data.value_counts() for all data set I obtain this:

```
Series([], dtype: int64)
```

The best result to obtain exactly why I want was with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx')

x = data['What is your age?'].value_counts().to_frame()

x.to_excel('dataframeforgraphs.xlsx') #Name of the file
```

So the results that are perfect as I wanted are these below:

There are how it looks in colab and how I need it for excel to create quick graphs

[image]
[image]

Now my problem is this code doesn't work for the full dataframe, so I was thinking about doing some kind of append in the excel document with a For, for each column but if I'm honest I'm a begginer with this kind of scripts, I would like to have some help/guidance with it.

This is my expected result (just 3 columns as example).

[image]

I tried with some codes by my own but nothing good to share, also I Google it to see what could I found but nothing close to it.

Many thanks for your attention

Comment: can you share the data on some cloud storage and share the link here

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Sorry is not possible to share this database

Comment: but this is similar case. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/miroslavsabo/young-people-survey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to iterate through every column (series) in your Dataframe, calculate value_counts, reindex to move the column's original values from the index to a column (creating a Dataframe) and then store each dataframe in a list. Then import `functools import reduce` and use the `reduce` function to merge your list of series into one Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

ages = {
    'age1':['10-20 years', '30-40 years', '40-50 years', '50-60 years', '', '', '30-40 years'],
    'age2':['10-20 years', '10-20 years', '10-20 years', '10-20 years', '50-60 years', '50-60 years', '50-60 years' ],
    'age3':['30-40 years', '40-50 years', '', '40-50 years', '30-40 years', '40-50 years', '30-40 years']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(ages)

dfs = []
for column in df:
    s = df[column].value_counts(dropna=False)
    s = s.to_frame().reset_index()
    s.rename(columns = {'index':'column'}, inplace=True) 
    dfs.append(s)

final_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left'), dfs)
print(final_df)
```

snapshot of result:

[image]

Note: if you want to change the output further, switch around formatting just let me know and I can probably help. I wrote this code to match your desired example, but there are definitely prettier ways to output this, but would need more info.

Comment: Yeah I think it works, I solved in other way